# ReactJS - warning message 'Hook useEffect has a missing dependency'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting the message in my console:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'calculateTotalProductsPrice'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

The code is working but I dont know if is this is the proper way of implementing useEffect

**Here I have a function that calculates the total price of my products and im calling it in my useEffect hook:**

```
  // Get all products the user added from my redux store
  const allProductsAddedByUser = useSelector(state => state.createCampaign.campaign_products)

  function calculateTotalProductsPrice() {
    const productsArray = Object.values(allProductsAddedByUser)
    const totalPrice = productsArray.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
      return prev + cur.quantity * 125.0
    }, 0)
    return totalPrice
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    calculateTotalProductsPrice()
  }, [allProductsAddedByUser])
```

And in my html, I'm calling the function like this:

```
<span>€ {calculateTotalProductsPrice()}</span>
```

If I put the `calculateTotalProductsPrice()` function inside my useEffect hook, the warning from console is gone, but then I can't call my function like I was doing, I'm getting the error `'calculateTotalProductsPrice' is not defined`. My function is now inside the useEffect hook, why cant I call her from outside?

```
  // Get all products the user added from my redux store
  const allProductsAddedByUser = useSelector(state => state.createCampaign.campaign_products)

  useEffect(() => {
    function calculateTotalProductsPrice() {
      const productsArray = Object.values(allProductsAddedByUser)
      const totalPrice = productsArray.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
        return prev + cur.quantity * 125.0
      }, 0)
      return totalPrice
    }
    calculateTotalProductsPrice()
  }, [allProductsAddedByUser])

 // Call function from my html
 <span>€ {calculateTotalProductsPrice()}</span> 
// Error calculateTotalProductsPrice is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About the warning message:**

There are 2 scenarios in this case.

The ***first*** is which is the current scenario when you need the `calculateTotalProductsPrice` function somewhere else in your code then you need to create outside of `useEffect`. One addition if that's the case which is passing it to so called dependency array, just like the following:

```
function calculateTotalProductsPrice() {
  // ... your calculation code
}

useEffect(() => {
  calculateTotalProductsPrice()
}, [calculateTotalProductsPrice])
```

In this case the warning message won't be shown again and in the same time it will be accessible in JSX as well, just like `<span>€ {calculateTotalProductsPrice()}</span>`.

***Second*** is once you don't need the `calculateTotalProductsPrice` function outside of `useEffect` then you can create inside of the callback as you did in your second example.

**About the accessibility of the function:**

And the reason why the function `calculateTotalProductsPrice` is not accessible outside once you declare in `useEffect` is becasue of JavaScript scope. The function only accessible inside of `useEffect` hook because of closure, from the documentation:

> A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed) with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment). In other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope from an inner function. In JavaScript, closures are created every time a function is created, at function creation time.

Read further here:

1. [JavaScript scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)
2. [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

I hope this helps!